# Shell script: split line

Tags: shell-script

I need to split a line with two string separated by an space like: `key value`.

I've tried:

```
key=$(awk -FS=" " {print $1} line)
value=$(awk -FS=" " {print $2} line)
```

But I'm getting:

> awk: line 2: missing } near end of file

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

An `awk` script on the command line should be single quoted:

```
awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }' filename
```

Notice the single quotes around `{ ... }`, and also that the correct way to set `FS` is through `-F`, or through `-v FS=...` or in a `BEGIN` block, but not with `-FS=...`.

Your command, the way you have written it, also assumes that `line` is a file name.

---

If `$line` is a string with a single space in it, you can separate it into two strings with

```
first_part=${line% *}   # removes the space and everything after it
second_part=${line#* }  # removes the space and everything before it
```

Likewise, if `$line` is a string with a `=` in it:

```
first_part=${line%=*}   # removes the = and everything after it
second_part=${line#*=}  # removes the = and everything before it
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use an array for splitting a line on spaces:

if **line** is a `string`

```
  arr=($line)
  key="${arr[0]}"
  value="${arr[1]}"
```

> Note:- If the first word of $line is * then the arr array will contain
>   all the filenames in the current directory. So to be on the safe side and avoid such situations , use
>
> `set -f; arr=($line); set +f
>   key="${arr[0]}"
>   value="${arr[1]}"`

If **line** is `file`

```
while read -r words
do
  set -- $words
  key=$1
  value=$2
done < line
```

Comment: `line` in the question is a filename.

Comment: @Kusalananda i thought it was a string, edited my answer for both the situations

Comment: In the first snippet, you are leaving the variable unquoted to employ word splitting. However you are also subject to filename expansion. If the first word of $line is `*` then the arr array will contain all the filenames in the current directory. You will have to `set -f; arr=($line); set +f`

Comment: @Kusalananda, I wouldn't assume that it's a file, given the apparent experience level of the question. I would put more trust in the words: "I need to split a line..."

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the suggestion, i did not considered that situation, added in my answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this, without using awk, that is inteded for more complex data manipulation.
`cut` bash command is all you need.

```
key="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
value="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
```

Comment: [Quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Answer (score 1):

## read

Just use `read`:

`read key value`

Everything before the first space on the line goes into `key` and everything after it (including any additional spaces) goes into `value`.

Comment: simple but valuable, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell's parameter expansion facilities instead of calling out to an external program:

```
key=${line%% *}     # from the end remove the longest string matching
                    # a space followed by any characters

value=${line#* }    # from the start remove the shortest string matching
                    # any characters followed by a space
```